# MySQL SELECT by reference with concatenation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Here's the problems...

I have 4 tables: `users`, `groups`, `users_groups`, and `emails`. Note that `users_groups` references both the `groups` and `users` table. In other words, each time a user joins a group, the userId and groupId is entered into the users_groups table. A user can join multiple groups.

```
CREATE TABLE app.users (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`firstName` INT NOT NULL ,
`lastName` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.groups (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`groupName` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.users_groups (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`groupId` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE app.emails (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`userId` INT NOT NULL ,
`email` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now I would like to query these tables and display the result like this:

```
 +---------+-------------------+--------------+
 |name     |emails             |groups        |
 +---------+-------------------+--------------+
 |John Doe |johndoe@mail.com,  |group1,group2,|
 |         |johndoe2@mail.com  |group3        |
 +---------+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: I think it's better to [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) ids instead of names; it's safer and enables you to find the email/group/etc for editing/deletion.

Comment: I don't understand, especially "ids instead of names" part. Please expain a bit more. Also note that I'm going to use the results to display in HTML format.

Comment: In the `emails` column you have email addresses, I'd recommend email ids. Then if you want to remove some address from John Doe, you could do it because you have the id. Though this requires you to execute multiple queries, but I think it's worth it.

Comment: All of my tables have ids. 'id' is the primary key for all tables. Perhaps you're mistaking visual/queried table for the actual table?

Comment: I thought you wanted the result of the query to look like above

Comment: Oh, I understand what you mean now. I didn't fetch the Id column for the sake of simplifying my question. In a real query I almost always take the primary key with each row. That is what you meant right?

Comment: Yes. Get all the id's, then get their additional data if needed (`select * from emails where id in (...)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) for that:

```
select  concat(u.Firstname, ' ', u.Lastname) as name
,       group_concat(distinct e.email separator ',') as emails
,       group_concat(distinct g.groupName separator ',') as groups
from    users u
left join
        users_groups ug
on      ug.userId = u.id
left join
        groups g
on      g.Id = ug.GroupId
left join
        emails e
on      e.UserId = u.Id
group by
        u.Id
,       u.Firstname
,       u.Lastnmae
```

Comment: I think you need `group_concat(DISTINCT e.email)` and `group_concat(DISTINCT g.groupName)`, because of the two left joins to `user_groups` and `emails`.

Comment: & @ypercube works great except the name is returning as 0 (zero)

Comment: @ypercube: Good point, edited in answer!  @Chad: Try using `concat` instead of `+` (also edited)